# JS regex not working on iPhone browser specifically - not sure why

Tags: javascript, ios, regex

I recently made some changes to code and was made aware that one of the pages that was updated does not work on the iPhone browser.  Sure enough, it didn't, but worked in all other browsers I tested.

Can anyone see something or give some insight as to why this particular line of code would fail on an iphone browser, but works elsewhere?  There is something about the regex that iPhone does not like and I need to make it compatible.  Note that the browser errors on this line not that the regex itself is failing if that makes sense.

I don't know of a way to see the debug info on an iphone browser to see if any information is provided.  I do know that if I remove the regex pattern from below the page works again on iPhone which tells me that is the problem.

```
return this.optional(element) || /^(\*\.|((?!-)[a-z0-9-]{1,255}(?<!-)\.))((?!-)[a-z0-9-]{1,255}(?<!-)\.)*[a-z]{2,}$/i.test(value);
```

Comment: `There is something about the regex that iPhone does not like` - it's the regex *lookbehind* that Safari can't understand - https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind

Comment: @Jaromanda X - any way around this or a way to change the regex to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: possibly, but I'm no regex expert - in fact, I avoid regex if I can - looking at that code you posted, I have no idea what the regex is attempting to test ... so, I can't offer any alternatives - I simpy answered your question - *Can anyone see something or give some insight as to why this particular line of code would fail on an iphone browser* - since you seem to know regex well enough to create that piece of code, then surely you can figure out a workaround (lookbehinds have only worked in other browsers for at most 3 YEARS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safari on iOS does not support lookbehind (at the time of writing). Your regex uses lookbehind here: `(?<!-)`

You can avoid that lookbehind by replacing this part:

```
[a-z0-9-]{1,255}(?<!-)
```

with this:

```
[a-z0-9-]{0,254}[a-z0-9]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to match double hyphens, you can write the pattern using a single negative lookahead asserting not `--` in the string:

```
^(?!.*--)(?:\*|[a-z0-9-]{1,255})\.[a-z0-9-]{1,255}\.[a-z]{2,}$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!.*--)` Negative lookahead, assert not `--` to the right
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\*` Match `*`
  - `|` Or Or
  - `[a-z0-9-]{1,255}` Match 1-255 chars `a-z` `0-9` `-`
- `)` Close non capture group
- `\.[a-z0-9-]{1,255}` Match `.` and 1-255 chars `a-z` `0-9` `-`
- `\.[a-z]{2,}` Match 2 or more chars a-z
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/c1gblY/1)